# How to write Django class-based view for form displaying and submission from other template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I have a ModelForm that I’d like to display in multiple places. For instance, in a ListView, underneath the list of articles. I can do this by putting it in `get_context_data()` in the ListView. I’d also like to display the form in its own template.

I’ve created a view for the form, but am not sure how to actually write it.

I’ve defined a `get_absolute_url()` in my model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('article', args=self.id)
```

The view for the form itself is:

`Views.py`

```
class ArticleSubmitView(CreateView):
    model = Article
    form_class = ArticleSubmitForm
    # is initial necessary?
    inital = {'title': '', 'text': '', 'categories': '', 'city': ''}
    # success url not necessary because model has get_absolute_url
    # however it does not redirect to the article
    template_name = 'articles/article-submit.html'
    # handle post data from other template/view
    # ???
```

The template includes the form (same thing for the ListView template).

`article-submit.html`

```
{% extends 'articles/base.html' %}
{% block article-submit %}
    {% include 'articles/article-form.html' %}
{% endblock article-submit %}
```

The form submits to the url that calls the CreateView:

`article-form.html`

```
<form action="{% url 'article-submit' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <!--- etc. --->
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import ArticlesView, ArticleSubmitView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ArticlesView.as_view(), name='articles'),
    # some urls left out for brevity
    url(r'^article-submit/$', ArticleSubmitView.as_view(), name='article-submit'),
]
```

However, the form does not submit from the list template, nor does it submit from the form template itself. It also doesn’t redirect, or show any error messages.

What am I doing wrong?

[Full code is available here](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/56bdaf52094dd7b99b255a3cae458227#file-views-py).

edit:

Checking to see if the form is valid or not like this shows me that the form is actually not valid:

```
class ArticleSubmitView(CreateView):
    model = Article
    form_class = ArticleSubmitForm
    # success url not necessary because model has get_absolute_url
    # however it does not redirect to the article
    template_name = 'articles/article-submit.html'
    # handle post data from other template/view
    # ???
    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('form is valid')
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print('form is invalid')
        print(form.errors)
```

However I get:
`AttributeError at /article-submit/`
`'ArticleSubmitForm' object has no attribute 'errors'`

Same thing happens when rendering the form as just {{ form }}

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do several things at once -  custom template rendering instead of just using `{{ form }}`, `MultiModelForm` from a third party app, and submitting from one url to another. It would be easier to debug if you tried to do one of these at a time instead of all at once. If you try printing `form.errors` in the `form_invalid` method it might show what's going wrong. If that doesn't help, try simplifying your views and templates as much as possible, and get a simple example working first.

Comment: @Alasdair yeah true. I just tried printing form.errors, and have edited the OP to reflect this. Going to try using just {{ form }} next. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I don’t need django-betterforms. A regular modelform works just fine. There were some other mistakes as well.

This is the code.

`models.py`

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('article', kwargs={'pk': self.id})
```

`views.py`

```
class ArticleSubmitView(CreateView):
    model = Article
    form_class = ArticleForm
    template_name = 'articles/article-submit.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('form is valid')
        print(form.data)
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.author = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('article', kwargs={'pk': obj.id}))
```

The urls and templates remain (largely) as above.